# why map request to route in mvc3 razor not works?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i create a simple mvc3 razor web application.
on it i have a controller and an action like this:

```
public class DownloadController : Controller
{       
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return File(@"\Files\MyFile.zip", "compress/zip");
    }

}
```

on my view i write these:

```
    @Html.ActionLink("Downlod file","Index","Download")
```

and

```
    <a href="Files/MyFile.zip">download it</a>
```

the first line works good and use Index action result but second not use index action result.
i register a wrote in 
Global.asax file to mape secound request to index action result but it not works

this code:

```
routes.MapRoute("downloadroute",
                "Files/",
                 new { controller = "Download", action = "Index", id =    
                 UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
```

but not works this rout 
whats the wrong?

its my complete global file contents

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
        );


        routes.MapRoute("downloadroute",
                        "Files/",
                     new { controller = "Download", action = "Index", 
                          id =UrlParameter.Optional }
                    );
```

thanks all

Comment: Do you have another setting on you routing config?

Comment: @Ikaso yes i edit my post and put my all routes in global file

Comment: The routes are matched in declaration order. Put the `downloadroute` before the `Default` route.

Comment: i Put the downloadroute before the Default route but not works yet

Comment: Did you recompile after changing the routing config?

Answer (score 0):

Your route conflicts with physical folder `Files`. You can rename your folder to resolve this conflict, or change route url (and put that route before default route):

```
routes.MapRoute("downloadroute",
                "Downloads/",
                 new { controller = "Download", action = "Index" }
                );
```

And use absolute path instead of relative:

```
<a href="@Url.Content("~/Downloads")">download it</a>
```

Comment: i want when user click on this  href link it goes to index action in download controller but it not works